# Designing data templates for WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, xaml

Using WPF, XAML, VS2008, and Blend 2 (or 3 Beta preferred), what is your process for creating data templates? Do you have a process for testing the data template's appearance WITHOUT spinning up your app just to test how the data looks? Is there a process I can use in Blend to make developing data templates more graphical?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify data at design-time through Blend, or (to get it working in VS as well) do this:

- Create a subclass of the object that you set as your DataContext.
- In the constructor of this subclass, set the properties to some test values.
- Declare an instance of the subclass as a resource.
- Set the DataContext to this resource.
- Remember to clear or set the DataContext to something sensible at runtime, otherwise users will see your design-time data.

Works in Silverlight as well.

Here's some example code:

```
// The object (in a list) that'll be bound as our ListBox ItemsSource
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

// Our design-time data. Note that we add list items in the constructor
public class PersonDesignTimeData : ObservableCollection<Person>
{
    public PersonDesignTimeData()
    {
        this.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Fred", LastName = "Smith" });
        this.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Brown" });
        this.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Dave", LastName = "Jones" });
    }
}
```

Window1.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="DesignTimeDataDemo.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DesignTimeDataDemo"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:PersonDesignTimeData x:Key="PersonDesignTimeData"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="root" DataContext="{StaticResource PersonDesignTimeData}">
        <ListBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="200">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use the above solution for design time data. Use the blend designtime libraries, they work in visual studio and are readily available in the SDK.
The way described above will consume memory at runtime for the resource instance, this will only instantiate the class at designtime.

Using the above example as a base you would do the same as the previous answer but reference it in the xaml like this:

```
<Window x:Class="DesignTimeDataDemo.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DesignTimeDataDemo"

xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:DesignInstances="clr-namespace:Mrwa.Mmis.Field.Client.Feature.Defect.ViewModel"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance IsDesignTimeCreatable=True, Type=DesignInstances:PersonDesignTimeCreatable}"

Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid x:Name="root" >
    <ListBox
        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
        >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="200">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```